# Varible substitution insdie json data in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-groovy

'{{ lookup(\"cyberarkpassword\", {\"appid\": \"component\", \"query\": \"safe=component-name;folder=root;object=$HOST_NAME-svcaccount-$HOST_IP\",\"output\": \"Password\"}).0.password }}'

I am assigning the above json data to one variable like the below

```
def cyberark='{{ lookup(\\"cyberarkpassword\\", {\\"appid\\": \\"component\\", \\"query\\": \\"safe=component-name;folder=root;object=$HOST_NAME-svcaccount-$HOST_IP\\",\\"output\\": \\"Password\\"}).0.password }}'
```

I am passing this cyberark variable to the ansible extra variable as ansible_ssh_passwd, the output is like below.

```
ansible_ssh_password='{{ lookup("cyberarkpassword", {"appid": "component", "query": "safe=component-name;folder=root;object=$HOST_NAME-svcaccount-$HOST_IP","output": "Password"}).0.password }}'
```

I don't know how to substitute this $HOST_NAME and $HOST_IP variable in json_data which is passing to the ansible.

Answer (score 0):

To access environment variables on a controller host (I hope I got your problem right) you can use `env` lookup plugin.

```
foo: '{{ lookup("env", "HOST_NAME") }}'
```